# Chart.js chart.update() method is not doing anything

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am working with Chart.js. I have a chart that can display the data. I also have different datasets that I would like to interchange on a button press. 
All the datasets are in an array and should just be interchanged with my method. Once I changed all the values, I call the `update()` method. Nothing happens!

I have checked the content of `char.data.datasets.data` and it does in fact contain the current data. The only thing is, that Chart.js does not seem to want to update.

What am I missing here?

The function that updates the chart:

```
let getValues = function(dataset, label)
{
  return firebase.database().ref("/data/" + dataset).once("value").then(function(snapshot)
  {
    var amazon = snapshot.val().Amazon;
    var google = snapshot.val().Google;
    var facebook = snapshot.val().Facebook;
    var twitter = snapshot.val().Twitter;


    chart.data.datasets.data = [];
    chart.data.labels = [];
    chart.data.datasets.label = null;

    chart.data.datasets.data = [amazon, google, facebook, twitter];
    chart.data.labels = names;
    chart.data.datasets.label = label;
    chart.update();
    console.log(chart.data.datasets.data);
  });
}
```

If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 9):

`chart.data.datasets` is an array of datasets, not a single dataset. `datasets` does not have its own `data` and `label` attributes. Rather, each individual `dataset` in the array has its own `data` and `label` attributes. You therefore cannot do `datasets.data` or `dataset.label`.

If you want to update the `data` or `label` variable of a specific dataset, you need to select that object from the array. To select the first dataset, simply use `datasets[0]`:

```
chart.data.datasets[0].data = [amazon, google, facebook, twitter];
chart.data.datasets[0].label = label;
```

If you want to update all datasets, use a `forEach` loop to iterate through the array:

```
chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data = [amazon, google, facebook, twitter];
    dataset.label = label;
});
```

---

Two more points:

One other possible problem is that the `names` variable is not initialized anywhere, though it could be that you just didn't include that part of the code in your question.

Also, why do you have the following three lines of code, if you just reassign all the values in the next three lines of code?

```
chart.data.datasets.data = [];
chart.data.labels = [];
chart.data.datasets.label = null;
```

Comment: I have a similar error but in my case, update() method is updating the chart the first time but not after that.

Comment: This was the case for me. You have to modify that exact object from the datasets array in order for the .update() function to take effect. Thanks!

Comment: @DriLLFreAK100 this is not correct. You can also replace the dataset objects